# Changing the name of link to not display website url php

Tags: php

Is there a way to have my link to say click here instead of the long website URL using PHP?

Here is the string I am using.

```
<a href=".$row['link']." target='_blank' style='color:#FF0000'>".$row['link']."</a>
```

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes, change `>".$row['link']."</a>` to `>Click here</a>`

Comment: I tried that and receive error messages

Comment: What I posted will work, show what you posted when you tried, and what error messages you got

Comment: It worked Thanks. I feel dumb now I been up all day my brain is fried

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href='".$row['link']."' target='_blank' style='color:#FF0000'>Click!</a>";
```

or in html:

```
<a href='<?php echo $row['link'];?>' target='_blank' style='color:#FF0000'>Click!</a>
```

Comment: It worked Thanks. I feel dumb now I been up all day my brain is fried

Answer (score 1):

You are missing title and text see here.

```
<a href=".$row['link']." target='_blank' style='color:#FF0000' title="Click here">Click here</a>
```